How to use sanity.io image in tailwind bg class?
I am trying to use a sanity.io image as a background image url in a tailwind class (next.js 14).
When I view page source I can see the cdn image url, however it doesent render on he page when I use urlFor(data.mainImage).url().
This is not working:
data?.mainImage ? urlFor(data.mainImage).url() : 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1549308/pexels-photo-1549308.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=2000'

Hardcoding the value works:
<section className={`bg-[url('https://cdn.sanity.io/images/0he7nz2b/production/6970de59aa24da2973e3892c2f43231ef132fcee-1680x419.png')] bg-Header bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center ${height} ${className}`}>

I have tried saving the value into a variable first and conditionaly rendering the component.
Any ideas? :)
